# Find repeated value in two sheets with multiple results in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to extract from a worksheet (Sheet 1) all values ​​using the code below, it does not return any value.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$11,SMALL(IF($A1=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11,ROW($A$3:$A$13)- MIN(ROW($A$3:$A$13))+1,""),COLUMN()-4)), "")
```

I need to bring all of the results in column "E" to the worksheet (Sheet 2) when the value of column "A" is equal in both worksheets, and fill in the next column if the value in column "E" is not repeated.

[image: Sheet 1]

The result needs to look like this:

[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: You have 2 options: 1) VBA code to get the values and then transpose them to destiny sheet. 2) If your data is always the same size (for example, if you know 100% sure that max results of a `Código Interno` is an exact number, then you could use a complex array formula to get the `RESULTADO` you need and transpose them

Comment: Also, you coulld try to resume your data by PivotTables? Indeed, it is the fastest way to get all `RESULTADO` related to each `CÓDIGO INTERNO` but it would not be transposed, it would be just 2 columns.

Comment: I believe VBA is the safest way to accomplish this task, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns the data is always the same size. Already by PivotTables does not solve for me.

Comment: If the data is always the same size, then it will be easier for you to code something to work. Just make a sub in VBA to reorganize your range as you wish.